# Need help identifying the underlying plot of a website for scraping purposes (selenium stopped working, only workable with JavaScript execution )

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I've been running a python script to extract items we purchased from a website(so it's behind the login page. We can download them as a file but it's missing certain details) for more than a few years now, but it suddenly stopped working.

To fix it I'm encountering some challenges in understanding its behavior. I'm seeking assistance in identifying the underlying plot or structure of the website, particularly with regards to the following aspects:

1. I have to open the page with JavaScript Execution: The desired page seem to be accessible only after executing JavaScript code, specifically `javascript:linkOpen()`. Without this step,  it forces the client to redirect to its top page.
2. URL Changes: After the initial page load, the website appends a string, such as `#list_0_****`, to the end of the URL. I'm curious about the purpose and significance of this URL modification.
3. Element Accessibility: Although the desired elements such as `/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[12]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/form/select` are present in the page source inspector and can also be identified in the output of `driver.page_source`, I'm still unable to locate them with Selenium selectors. I suspect that the website developer may have implemented some techniques or structures that make the elements inaccessible through traditional means. So far only way to access it I've found is to access it via JavaScript.
   (*As you can see in the above full path it's not in another frame. I checked this multiple times.Even the top most element in the page is inaccessible)

So I developed a function to make it feel like its usual Selenium selector.

```py
def execute_js_action(action, target, value=None):
    if action == "find_by_id":
        js_code = f"return document.getElementById('{target}');"
    elif action == "find_by_xpath":
        js_code = f"return document.evaluate('{target}', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;"
    elif action == "read_selected":
        js_code = f"return document.getElementById('{target}').options[document.getElementById('{target}').selectedIndex].value;"
    elif action == "select_option":
        js_code = f"document.getElementById('{target}').value = '{value}';"
    elif action == "click_element":
        js_code = f"document.getElementById('{target}').click();"
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid action provided.")

    return driver.execute_script(js_code)
```

Any insights or workarounds for accessing these elements with traditional selenium selector would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just so you know, you can use [css selectors with selenium](https://www.scrapingbee.com/webscraping-questions/selenium/how-to-find-elements-css-selector-selenium/).

Comment: Without being able to reproduce this issue, it's unlikely we'll be able to help.

Comment: Yeah I know. It's like it is null, no selector is working and this started happening suddenly.
Wish I could share the source, give credentials and have people access to it to analyze but it's just too sensitive for that. 
I was hoping there would be some web dev who achieved the same against scaping before.